# Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changeType') How to solve this in Apps script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, triggers, onchange, changetype

I'm creating a chatbot by using Uchat and the relevant data is stored in google spread sheets. I have added some triggers as well and the triggers works fine with 0% error rate but the function **"onChange"** don't run it shows an error mentioning *Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changeType')* the main feature is to record the data in the spread sheets by inserting a new row. Please help me to slove this issue I'm currunetly working as an intern in a company so I'm using company email to get my answers. Thank you Cheers!

This is my code:

````
function onChange(e){
  changeType = e.changeType;
  sheetName = e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName();
  Logger.log(changeType);
  Logger.log(sheetName);
  if (e.changeType !== "INSERT_ROW" || e.source.getActiveSheet().getSheetName() !== "Booking Appointment List") return;

  Utilities.sleep(1000);

  createCalendarEvent();
}```


[This the error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n3EzY.png)

I'm expecting any ideas to slove this error. Thank You.
````

Comment: About your error of `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'changeType')`, how did you run your script? If you have directly run your script, such an error occurs because of no event object `e`. If you want to run your script by the OnChange trigger, please run the script by firing the OnChange trigger. [Ref](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable) Please be careful about this.

Comment: Yes, I did run the script directly hence the changeType doesn't do the change to INSERT_ROW while the details must be recorded in the google spreadsheet. Thank you so much and noted I'll follow the reference.

Comment: Thank you for replying. I'm glad you understood the reason for your current issue.

Comment: About `actually i removed the dates and it worked. No errors. thanks.`, I'm glad your issue was resolved. When your issue was resolved, can you post it as an answer? By this, it will be useful for other users who have the same issue.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I was able to solve the issue but unfortunately, I can't share any images but what I would say is that the issue was not in the code but in the Google spreadsheets hence there was a booking ID that needs to be followed once all the variable matched each other the rows were able to insert to the sheet. Now it's running smoothly. If anyone has this issue, please check your spreadsheets and if needed delete rows and try again hence it worked for me. If you are dealing with Uchat as well check the assigned variables. Cheers!